# Laravel check if storage exists is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-filesystem

I'm trying to check if file already exist in the storage by

```
if(Storage::exists($request->file_name)):
    dd(var_dump("it did exist"));
else:
    dd(var_dump("it did not exist"));
endif
```

but it always return a string "it did exist" even though the file is actually deleted or the file did not exist, any ideas, help?

I'm sure there's no problem on my storage location set up as I'm having no problem when uploading a file to the storage,

```
Storage::put($file_name, File::get($file));
```

PS: I'm on Laravel 5.0

UPDATE:

here's my filesystems.php from the config folder of my Laravel 5.0

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. A "local" driver, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based drivers are available for your choosing. Just store away!
    |
    | Supported: "local", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'default' => 'local',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => 's3',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => storage_path().'/employee_documents/',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => 'your-key',
            'secret' => 'your-secret',
            'region' => 'your-region',
            'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
        ],

        'rackspace' => [
            'driver'    => 'rackspace',
            'username'  => 'your-username',
            'key'       => 'your-key',
            'container' => 'your-container',
            'endpoint'  => 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/',
            'region'    => 'IAD',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Are you sure your default storage set correctly in config filesystems.php ?

Comment: @vijaykumar: yes im sure as I'm having no error or any issue when uploading a file to the storage (file uploaded successfully)

Comment: I'm sure. It might be problem with path only. Just dump $request->file_name .Check that path is corrent

Comment: @vijaykumar: it gives me "MMPH13-0012[x]3[x]Juliver Galleto Letter of Intent.docx" which means the file name is sent right to the controller. any ideas?

Comment: No idea @Code Demon. But share your filesytems.php i will check once in my machine.

Comment: @vijaykumar: please see my updated post.

Comment: What's coming back from `$request->file_name`? Do you know you have a value there?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Laravel 5.5 and the solution was to use

```
Storage::disk('public')->exists($file_name)
```

instead of

```
Storage::exists($file_name)
```

On my config/filesystem.php by default I have two types of local disks (local and public) and I wasn't aware of it:

```
    'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

],
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know the reason why it's not working in your case. I tried in my machine it's working fine.

I tried to debug what's inside `Storage::exits` it uses same `return file_exists($path);`

It might be the reason

> Results of the file_exists() are cached

Try these things

1. php artisan config:cache
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan view:clear
4. chmod -R 777 storage/ or chown -R webuser:webuser storage/

Comment: Don't ever use chmod -R 777 in production. https://medium.com/@oliverjkb/why-chmod-777-is-internet-advice-from-hell-2fb4049f1137

Answer (score 1):

This may can help you. It's working with Laravel5.4:

```
Storage::exists('dir/'. $filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(File::exists('filePath')){
     dd(var_dump("it did exist"));

}else{
   dd(var_dump("it did not exist"));
}
```

Please try above code

Comment: I'm using Laravel Storage facade not file facade.